# 5.58.1 causes Undefined index: job_id in Civi\Aws\Subscriber\Mailing

Tags: civimail, upgrade, aws

Upgraded to 5.58.1 this week and now AWS extension causing errors which slow down mail processing and lead to civimail mailings not going out. Each address leaves an error in the log from /civicrm/admin/job?action=view&id=1&reset=1:

```
 Undefined index: job_id in Civi\Aws\Subscriber\Mailing->addTrackingDataHeaders() (line 153 of .........sites/all/civiextensions/aws/Civi/Aws/Subscriber/Mailing.php).
```

May be related to Drush errors I get:

```
Error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no
longer supported in
/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/aws/aws.civix.php,
line 246
```

Answer (score 2):

You can consider switching to the [AirMail extension](https://github.com/aghstrategies/com.aghstrategies.airmail) which supports AWS. Instructions for setup are [here](https://github.com/aghstrategies/com.aghstrategies.airmail/blob/master/docs/ses.md).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this extension? https://github.com/mecachisenros/aws

You're using php 8 and that extension isn't compatible with it.